# I want to make my txt file safe

Tags: php, permissions

Current status.
I have to set
606 for my foobaa.txt.

I wrote a php code,
that read and write
foobaa.txt,

and I want to make the
permission of the foobaa.txt as
600.

But when I tested 600,
the PHP code can not read and write
foobaa.txt.

so I changed to 606 the foobaa.txt,
then my PHP code can read and write
the foobaa.txt.

this is problom, because

when someone put

ttp://blabla.foobaa.com/foobaa.txt

directly, then he can see the contents of the
foobaa.txt.

This is security hole.

so I want to make 600 for the
permission of the foobaa.txt,
but if I do so, then
the php code can not read and write
foobaa.txt.

I think the admin can modify some
apatch settings for we can set the
txt file's permission as 600.

or do I have to do some other things?

like .htaccess or something.

Answer (score 8):

Your PHP code runs as the web server, not the user that is SSH'ing into the account and changing the permissions.  So if the text file is readable by the script, it is readable by the server. You will want to control outside users' access to the file by one of a couple of methods.

1. Put the file outside your `DocumentRoot`, so that the script can access it, but it's impossible to request by HTTP.
2. Put the file in a directory with a `.htaccess` file that reads simply `Deny From All`.  You could also protect the file individually, but it's likely that you'll have other, related files that should be kept private. You can just put those in the same directory.

Comment: "web server" means apatch?
"runs as web server" measns that
my php code runs yelling that
"Hey! I am apatch! Hey! I am apatch! Hey! I am apatch!"

Answer (score 2):

You could restrict access through .htaccess:

```
<Files foobaa.txt>
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

or something similar. But this isn't perfect... better would be moving the file outside your public_html (or equivalent) folder.

Comment: oh, that's great !
I completely forgot to use
outside of public_html.

thanks!